# How to stop sending data in an EventBus if found the a specific value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, ecmascript-6, web-frameworks

i am working on Vuejs components with Javascript. I have one component that emits an EventBus to other component. On the sender component i have a list of indexes that goes one by one to the other component evaluating if its true. Eg:

```
listA: 0
listA: 0
listA: 0
listA: 0
listA: 1
listA: 0
listA: 0
```

On the receiver component i get the listA one by one. I am doing a switch case to see when i am receiving the value 1 and returning that to my html in a div with a specific css. In my switch i cancel the eventbus when encountering the value 1 like this:

```
switch(listA) {
   case 1: 
      return something
      EventBus.$off('event-message');
   case 0: 
      // do nothing
}
```

This is just working fine...but, my problem is when i have to use this two or more times in the same page for different divs. I want to use the same event for all divs otherwise the code gets longer and longer and when i am cancel the event in one div it cancels the events in all of them. Does anyone have an ideia to return the value 1 without cancel the event and if its encounters the value 1 stops seeing the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Vue's `EventBus` has 3 ways to use `$off`:

- `EventBus.$off()` - removes all handlers from all events
- `EventBus.$off('event-name')` - removes all handlers from a single event
- `EventBus.$off('event-name', handler)` - removes a specific handler from a single event

In your case, using `EventBus.$off('event-message');` removes all event handlers of the `event-message` event.

To unsubscribe the current event handler from the event:

```
// The event handler function.
const eventMessageHandler = () => { ... }

// Listen to the event
EventBus.$on('event-message', eventMessageHandler);

// Stop listening - unsubscribe current handler
EventBus.$off('event-message', eventMessageHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm totally against using the event bus, it's like if you take a speaker out of the crowd and shout GABRIEL, how much gabriel could hear that message and respond, that's the effect of the event bus, It screams and everyone can hear, this can be a big problem for your application, I recommend using event propagation until you get to the ideal component through the $ emits and properties.
But to stop the event it is necessary to trigger the event.
EventBus.$off('event-message', nameFunctionAction);
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events

Comment: There are many legimate uses for an event bus, so a blanket policy like this can be as harmful as using an event bus for everything.

One example I can think of, say you want different instances of the same component to be able to communicate. A menu popover where you only want one to display on the screen (and for all others to close when one is displayed). Obviously you have no emit chain between component instances, no idea where they might mount. Your only options are DOM traversal, Vuex, a custom browser Event (not very Vue) or an event bus.